# X11 - How to invert axis on touchscreen matrix?

Tags: xorg, input, xinput, touch-screen

I have a tablet that I flashed Fedora Silverblue on, but the touchscreen has the Y-axis inverted when the device is on landscape, and X-Axis inverted portrait mode.

I've disabled wayland to use xinput on xorg, and no luck so far.

---

This is the matrix currently on the tablet:

```
Landscape (Clockwise 90°)     Portrait
[ 0 -1 0 ]                    [ 1 0 0 ]
[ 1  0 0 ]                    [ 0 1 0 ]
[ 0  0 1 ]                    [ 0 0 1 ]
```

With the current matrix in portrait mode, the Y-axis is normal, but the X-axis is inverted. Is there a way to fix the inversion?

I tried applying the inverse of the Landscape matrix (below), but that only flipped the inverse Y-axis to inverted X-axis in landscape.

`xinput set-prop ID "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1`

```
[  0 1 0 ]
[ -1 0 1 ]
[  0 0 1 ]
```

Note: this is similar to the question here:

[Use xorg.conf to fix touchscreen X axis reversed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683430/use-xorg-conf-to-fix-touchscreen-x-axis-reversed)

Except, I'm trying to figure out how to revert the axis via xinput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of Trial and Error, but this was the solution I came up with:

1. Find the touch screen device via `xinput`:

   ```
   xinput
   ```

   Note down the device ID that will be used.
2. Find the matrix of the device (in this case `10`) that is currently used on the current screen rotation:

   ```
   xinput list-props 10 | grep Matrix
   ```

   In this example, my tablet has the screen rotated 90° clockwise:

   ```
   Coordinate Transformation Matrix (179): 0.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
   ```

   Which translates to:

   ```
   x: [ 0 -1 1 ]
   y: [ 1  0 0 ]
   z: [ 0  0 1 ]
   ```
3. Since we're finding the inverse of the Y-axis when the tablet is in landscape 90° clockwise, find the inverse of the matrix. (Any matrix calculator online would work).

   The inverse of the matrix above would be:

   ```
   x: [  0 1 0 ]
   y: [ -1 0 1 ]
   z: [  0 0 1 ]
   ```

   Since we only want to invert the Y-Axis, just cherry pick the Y-values in the matrix to the original matrix.
4. This leads us to the final step: Getting the final matrix which 'fixes' the inverted axis on the touch screen.

   ```
   x: [  0 -1 1 ] (taken from the original maxtrix)
   y: [ -1  0 1 ] (taken from the inverse matrix)
   z: [  0  0 1 ]
   ```

   And the command that 'fixes' the touch screen:

   ```
   xinput set-prop 10 "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 -1 0 1 0 0 1
   ```

---

Now the last step would be to repeat the steps above for other screen orientations and make the changes permanent via `udev` or something else.

Comment: This is obviously for X11. If someone knows how to make the changes for Wayland, then that would be appreciated as well!

Comment: You can use the name of the device instead of the id. For example: `xinput set-prop "ACME Touchscreen" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 -1 0 1 0 0 1`

Comment: Here's a question, what if the inverse of your original matrix is itself (an involutory matrix
)? My current TransformationMatrix is "-1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1" but I need to flip my X-axis.